# How to plot the 95% CLs exclusions when working with MG5/MA5?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics, beyond-the-standard-model

So I am a complete noob to phenomenology and I need to plot CL contours for a model I am working on. My model looks kinda like this
$$\mathcal{L} = g_{1}\{Fields\} + g_2\{Fields\}$$

and I need to plot contours for a $5\sigma$ discovery with $g_1 - g_2$ as my free parameters.

Considering, after adding cuts, my $N_s=\alpha$ and $N_b=\beta$, how do I move forward?

Comment: I find the question hard to understand.  Is $\cal L$ a Lagrangian or a likelihood?  Are $g_1$ and $g_2$ functions or parameters?  What are $N_s$ and $N_b$?

Comment: Hey, so $\mathcal{L}$ is the extended lagrangian.
$g_1, g_2$ are my couplings.
And, $N_s, N_b$ are my number of signal/background events normalized to some integrated luminosity after applying cuts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the details of your model, but if you have a prediction for the number of events $N$ as a function of some parameters $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n$ the simplest way is to use a $\chi^2$ likelihood to get the exclusion region with respect to the hypothesis where all $\theta$s are $0$

$$\chi^2(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n) = \frac{(N(\theta) - N(\theta=0))^2}{N(\theta = 0)}$$

The exclusion contour is then given by the inequality $\chi^2 < X$ where $X$ depends on the confidence level you want and the numbers of parameters. You can find the values in table 40.2 of [the PDG review.](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2021-rev-statistics.pdf)

For two parameters at $95\%$ it is $X=5.99$.